# Getting this error "at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)" while running javafx program

Tags: javafx

I am new in javafx. I am building a basic program in javafx.
But getting error "at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)" while running the program ...........
program is:

```
package myjfxapp;

import com.sun.javaws.Main;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class NewFXMain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("main.fxml"));
        Pane root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Fxml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="221.0" layoutY="58.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      <CheckBox layoutX="211.0" layoutY="152.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="CheckBox" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Your help will be obliged....

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the full stack trace, and identify which line in the code you posted is throwing the exception.

Comment: And please update your code with the modifications proposed by @James_D, because until the wrong import is there and you are using that class to get the resource it is impossible to identify the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You used

```
new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource(...));
```

and for some reason imported `com.sun.javaws.Main`. Your class is called `NewFXMain`, so you need

```
new FXMLLoader(NewFXMain.class.getResource(...));
```

or just

```
new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(...));
```

Comment: I replaced the code but sorry to say the same problem still persist.

Comment: @weilkroft The *same* error, or a new one? It's very difficult to believe you get exactly the same error.

Comment: I don't know the problem sir but yes it is the same error.

Comment: Post the complete stack trace in your question (as previously requested).

Comment: I've added the stack trace @James_D

Comment: @weilkroft Where is the stack trace?